# concatenate files without copying their contents

Tags: c++, linux, file, file-io

(In C/C++/Linux)

Is there a way to concatenate file A and file B (or actually append one A's content to that of  B) only by altering the file system without the overhead of data copying? File A then can be discarded.

Thanks

Comment: So if you have 2 files of 1 byte each, you end up with 1 file containing 2 bytes? That will be a problem on block-oriented storage - and most modern commercial non-volatile storage is block-oriented, short of NOR flash. But anything SATA or USB-attached is, as are SD cards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the files were block-structured, and if the OS supported block-structured files (as some do) then (in principle) yes. But as you are asking about Linux, I assume you are talking about a byte-stream oriented file system, where a disk block may not be completely used. In this case, some copying is inevitable and in practice you have to copy the whole file.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own file system (e.g. with FUSE) that provides pseudo files for cheap concatenation. But I guess that would be overkill (for any use case), as you have to care about references and stuff.